# Xamarin.Forms SQLite WinPhone

Tags: android, sqlite, windows-phone-8, xamarin

I'm working on an app using Xamarin that will run on Android and Windows Phone 8.
The app has a local database.
It works fine on Android, but I'm facing a crash on WinPhone.
When the app tries to update an item on database, it says "no such column: SendBill".

By debugging the app, I can see it calls `connection.CreateTable<TTable>();`, where TTable is a type of RouteMobile.

My RouteMobile:

```
public class RouteMobile: IModelBase
{
    public RouteMobile() { }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Code{ get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public string DtExec { get; set; }

    public string Situation { get; set; }

    public int SendBill{ get; set; }

    public int QtdBillsToPrint { get; set; }

    public int QtdNotificationsToPrint { get; set; }

    public int QtdDebitNotificationsToPrint { get; set; }

    #region Sincronization

    public Int32 IdServer { get; set; }

    public DateTime SyncVersion { get; set; }

    public Boolean UpdateFlag { get; set; }

    #endregion

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public List<RoutePointMobile> RoutePointList { get; set; }
}
```

My IModelBase:

```
public interface IModelBase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the app app calls connection.Update(item);, where item is a instance of RouteMobile, it crashes:

```
{SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: no such column: SendBill
   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Update(Object obj, Type objType)
   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Update(Object obj)
   at IM.Data.BaseMobileDAO`1.Save[T](T item)
   at IM.Business.RouteMobileBO.Save(RouteMobile item)
   at IM.Business.RouteMobileBO.AjustRoutes(IList`1 lstRout)
   at IM.ViewModels.RoutListViewModel.get_ListRouts()}
```

Running on Android, it runs fine. On WinPhone it crashes.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem only happen on update or is it even connecting to the db at all because if not it may not be finding the db since Android and WP store local files in different locations.

Comment: I just saw that it happens on save, also. I think every command fails. But when the app creates the connection, it doesnt' fail.

Comment: How are you connecting to the db because I think if you don't set FailIfMissing=True when you try connecting and the db isn't there it will create a new one instead of throwing an exception which is why that isn't failing but trying to get/updating data does